# Python sys.exit with a number

Tags: python

```
if __name__ = '__main__':
    blah = False
    if something:
        blah = True

    if blah:
        sys.exit(1)            <--- is this necessary?
```

would program still exit with 1 if blah is False?

Comment: Then it will exit with `0`.

Comment: @ealeon How and why should it do so if `blah` is False? Then there is no way to reach the `sys.exit(1)` line...

Comment: @glglgl that was the whole point of the question, i thought sys.exit(1) is the default.

Comment: @ealeon No. A program is, when it exits, deemed as successful and thus exits with the exit code `0`.

Comment: @glglgl well i know that now...... I wasnt aware of that before asking the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `blah` is `False` then the `sys.exit(1)` line would not be executed.

Provided there is no other code following the code you posted, Python will exit normally, which means the exit code will be `0`, the same as if `sys.exit()` had been called without an argument.

Exit code meanings are a convention; 0 means success, anything else usually means there was a problem. Explicitly exiting the program with `sys.exit(1)` simply means the program adheres to that convention; it is signalling *something* to whatever started the script, namely that things didn't work out.

Some programs use exit codes for more than just failure communication; exit codes can be used to communicate a range of states, but that is entirely up to the program. Check the documentation to be sure what status codes mean, status codes are not really standardized, it is all more of a... guideline.

TLDR: the default exit code for *most* programs is `0`, meaning succes, and Python is no exception.